# I'm not able generate initial change log using Liquibase

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase

I will use Liquibase 3.1.0 from the shell to generate initial change log from *javax.persistence* annotated classes which resides in the packages *info.ggiv.cdr.commons.entity.** of my project. I have placed the *mysql-connector* and *liquibase-hibernate4* libraries in the *lib* directory of my Liquibase installation.
The libraries for Hibernate 3.4.0 are located in the folder */opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/all*:

```
gg@VM-WrkEnv:/opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/all$ ls -l
összesen 124
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 56 jan   12 19:46 antlr-2.7.7.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/required/antlr-2.7.7.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62 jan   12 19:45 c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/c3p0/c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 56 jan   12 19:46 dom4j-1.6.1.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/required/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 71 jan   12 19:45 ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/ehcache/ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 76 jan   12 19:45 hibernate-c3p0-4.3.0.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/c3p0/hibernate-c3p0-4.3.0.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 86 jan   12 19:46 hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/required/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 71 jan   12 19:46 hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/required/hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 82 jan   12 19:45 hibernate-ehcache-4.3.0.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/ehcache/hibernate-ehcache-4.3.0.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 75 jan   12 19:45 hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/jpa/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 71 jan   12 19:45 hibernate-envers-4.3.0.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/envers/hibernate-envers-4.3.0.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 88 jan   12 19:45 hibernate-infinispan-4.3.0.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/infinispan/hibernate-infinispan-4.3.0.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 94 jan   12 19:45 hibernate-infinispan-4.3.0.Final-tests.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/infinispan/hibernate-infinispan-4.3.0.Final-tests.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 78 jan   12 19:46 hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/required/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 93 jan   12 19:45 hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.0.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/jpa-metamodel-generator/hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.0.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 67 jan   12 19:46 hibernate-osgi-4.3.0.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/osgi/hibernate-osgi-4.3.0.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 82 jan   12 19:46 hibernate-proxool-4.3.0.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/proxool/hibernate-proxool-4.3.0.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 86 jan   12 19:45 infinispan-commons-6.0.0.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/infinispan/infinispan-commons-6.0.0.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 83 jan   12 19:45 infinispan-core-6.0.0.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/infinispan/infinispan-core-6.0.0.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 63 jan   12 19:46 jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/required/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 64 jan   12 19:46 javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/required/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 67 jan   12 19:46 jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/required/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 82 jan   12 19:46 jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/required/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 83 jan   12 19:45 jboss-marshalling-1.3.18.GA.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/infinispan/jboss-marshalling-1.3.18.GA.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89 jan   12 19:45 jboss-marshalling-river-1.3.18.GA.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/infinispan/jboss-marshalling-river-1.3.18.GA.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 98 jan   12 19:45 jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/infinispan/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 87 jan   12 19:46 jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/required/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 75 jan   12 19:45 jgroups-3.4.1.Final.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/infinispan/jgroups-3.4.1.Final.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 68 jan   12 19:45 link to slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/ehcache/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 78 jan   12 19:45 mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.4.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/c3p0/mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.4.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 66 jan   12 19:46 org.osgi.compendium-4.3.1.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/osgi/org.osgi.compendium-4.3.1.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 60 jan   12 19:46 org.osgi.core-4.3.1.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/osgi/org.osgi.core-4.3.1.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 66 jan   12 19:46 proxool-0.8.3.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/proxool/proxool-0.8.3.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 83 jan   12 19:45 rhq-pluginAnnotations-3.0.4.jar -> /opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/optional/infinispan/rhq-pluginAnnotations-3.0.4.jar
```

When I start Luquibase using the following command

```
gg@VM-WrkEnv:~/Projektek/CDR/src/CDR-Commons/src/main/java$ /opt/liquibase/liquibase --changeLogFile=/home/gg/Projektek/CDR/src/CDR-Commons/src/main/resources/changelog.xml --referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:info.ggiv.cdr.commons.entity.account,info.ggiv.cdr.commons.entity.contact,info.ggiv.cdr.commons.entity.descriptor.ds,info.ggiv.cdr.commons.entity.descriptor.ds.entry.field,info.ggiv.cdr.commons.entity.ds,info.ggiv.cdr.commons.entity.ds.entry,info.ggiv.cdr.commons.entity.ds.enty.field,info.ggiv.cdr.commons.entity.ds.field.type,info.ggiv.cdr.commons.entity.ds.field.type.simple,info.ggiv.cdr.commons.entity.event,info.ggiv.cdr.commons.entity.localization,info.ggiv.cdr.commons.entity.organization,info.ggiv.cdr.commons.entity.ou,info.ggiv.cdr.commons.entity.owner?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect --url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/cdr --username=root --password=****** --classpath=/opt/java-lib/hibernate-orm/lib/all generateChangeLog
```

from the folder where my sources resides, I get following output

```
WARNING 2014.01.13. 18:11:liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringDatabase as a Liquibase service because org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect is not in the classpath
WARNING 2014.01.13. 18:11:liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateEjb3Database as a Liquibase service because org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect is not in the classpath
WARNING 2014.01.13. 18:11:liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateClassicDatabase as a Liquibase service because org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect is not in the classpath
WARNING 2014.01.13. 18:11:liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.ext.hibernate.snapshot.SequenceSnapshotGenerator as a Liquibase service because org.hibernate.id.factory.IdentifierGeneratorFactory is not in the classpath
Liquibase 'generateChangeLog' Successful
```

and the generated change log file is empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd"/>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classpath attribute doesn't support directories of jars, you need to include the hibernate jars individually.

More easily, you should be able to add the hibernate jars to the "lib" dir in /opt/liquibase/liquibase. The shell script will find all jars in there and add them to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this one: https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/Hibernate+Integration . I think not all libraries are accepted.